# Receiving wrong value in main() after calling on change_global() function

Tags: c++, function, global-variables

This code is exactly as written in the book I'm using, but the example in the book shows that the third instance of cout in main() should provide the integer -10. Instead it provides 10. Why is my program not providing the actual value given to "glob" in the change_global() function? I'm aware the book is outdated, it is the 4th edition of Beginning C++ through Game Programming.

```
int glob = 10; // global variable

void access_global();
void hide_global();
void change_global();

int main()
{
    cout << "In main() glob is: " << glob << "\n\n";
    access_global();

    hide_global();
    cout << "In main() glob is: " << glob << "\n\n";

    change_global();
    cout << "In main() glob is: " << glob << "\n\n";
    
    return 0;
}

void access_global()
{
    cout << "In access_global() glob is: " << glob << "\n\n";
}

void hide_global()
{
    int glob = 0;
    cout << "In hide_global() glob is: " << glob << "\n\n";
}

void change_global()
{
    int glob = -10;
    cout << "In change_global() glob is: " << glob << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: `int glob = -10;` declares and initializes a local variable, distinct from and unrelated to a global variable named `glob` (which I assume exists, though it's not present in the code shown). That global variable remains unchanged.

Comment: Helpful reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

Comment: Sidenote: Learn to program in <language goes here> by <task goes here> books almost always suck, up-to-date or not. Here's [a list of known-good C++ programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: In the beginning I initialize int glob = 10 but it got cut off.

The example and the book both claim that when inside of the change_global() func, I have changed the global variable 'glob' and the console displays as such. Maybe this is just a case of the book being terribly wrong.

Comment: Your `main()` does not compile because there is no local or global variable `glob`. Also there is output in every function and in `main`. Which output is not as you expect? Are you sure you just copied the code from the book and did not change it?

Comment: I'm looking at the source code for the book downloaded from here: http://www.delmarlearning.com/companions/content/1305109910/datafiles/index.asp?isbn=1305109910  It is not the same as what you've typed, there is a global variable named `glob` and it is changed by the `change_global` function. Remove the `int` from `int glob = -10;`

Comment: I have edited the code to show that I did initialize a global variable `glob`. The code is 100% as the book shows, and the book specifically states I can do this to change `glob` to -10 in main().

Answer (score 0):

Posted by Retired Ninja

"I'm looking at the source code for the book downloaded from here: delmarlearning.com/companions/content/1305109910/datafiles/… It is not the same as what you've typed, there is a global variable named glob and it is changed by the change_global function. Remove the int from int glob = -10; – Retired Ninja 38 secs ago"

This solves my issue, thank you all for the help!